# How to define an environment to be another environment whose name is given by a macro?

Tags: macros, environments

Suppose that I wish to define a new environment `mynewenv` which is exactly as an existed environment `myenv**`, but the name is given in `\testmacro`. How do I get the *value* of `\testmacro` while making the definition?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\testmacro{myenv**}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { myenv** } { O{} }
  { My }
  { Env }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mynewenv } { O{} }
  {
    \expandafter \begin \expandafter { \testmacro }
  }
  {
    \expandafter \end \expandafter { \testmacro }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\testmacro{cleared} % This shouldn't affect "mynewenv"

\begin{document}

\begin{mynewenv}
  
\end{mynewenv}

Text in case of empty.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the body of the environment to have `\begin{test**}` so need to expand before the definition, I use an `ee` variant here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\testmacro{myenv**}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { myenv** } { O{} }
  { My }
  { Env }

\cs_new:Nn\my_def_env:nn{
\NewDocumentEnvironment { #1 } { O{} }
  {
    \begin { #2 }
  }
  {
    \end { #2 }
  }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_def_env:nn {ee}

\my_def_env:ee  {mynewenv} { \testmacro}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\testmacro{cleared} % This shouldn't affect "mynewenv"

\begin{document}

\begin{mynewenv}
  
\end{mynewenv}

Text in case of empty.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is mixing layers a bit to use the design layer NewDocumentEnvironment within the L3 programming layer code, but this minimises the changes from the original in the question.